# The fastest way to find all pairs of numbers in a list that differ not more than x

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

What I have now:

```
d = 0
res = 0
newlist = []
l = [4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1]

for el in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if abs(l[el] - l[j]) <= d and el != j and el not in newlist and j not in newlist:
            newlist.append(el)
            newlist.append(j)
            res += 1

print(res)
```

It works well and returns 2 which is correct(1,1; 1,1) but takes too much time. How can I make it work faster ? Thanks.

**For example** if list = [1, 1, 1, 1] and d = 0 there will be 2 pairs because you can use each number only once. Using (a, b) and (b, c) is not allowed and (a, b) with (b, a) is the same pair...

Comment: It definitely doesn't work well. Try your code snippet.

Comment: two values make one pair, for 'a' and 'b'  -- (a, b) and (b, a) are different?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan (a, b) and (b, a) is the same pair and a, b can't be used anymore

Comment: I don't think there is a solution faster than O(n^2) for this. You can try sorting first, which should be bit faster in practical.

Comment: Yes, but this part `el not in newlist and j not in newlist` doesn't refer to the list elements. That and what's being appended are the range values, not list values. So it's not even dealing with pairs in the list

Comment: How about (a,b) and (b,c)? and (a,c)?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath no, its allowed to use an element in pair only once, so if *a* and *b* are pair you can't count *a* and *c* as pair too

Comment: Please put all these into the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the list, then walk through it.

Once you have the list sorted, you can just be greedy: take the earliest pair that works, then the next, then the next... and you will end up with the maximum number of valid pairs.

```
def get_pairs(lst, maxdiff):
    sl = sorted(lst) # may want to do lst.sort() if you don't mind changing lst
    count = 0
    i = 1
    N = len(sl)
    while i < N:
        # no need for abs -- we know the previous value is not bigger.
        if sl[i] - sl[i-1] <= maxdiff:
            count += 1
            i += 2 # these two values are now used
        else:
            i += 1
    return count
```

And here's some code to benchmark it:

```
print('generating list...')
from random import randrange, seed
seed(0) # always same contents
l = []
for i in range(1000000):
    l.append(randrange(0,5000))

print('ok, measuring...')

from time import time

start = time();
print(get_pairs(l, 0))
print('took', time()-start, 'seconds')
```

And the result (with 1 million values in list):

```
tmp$ ./test.py 
generating list...
ok, measuring...
498784
took 0.6729779243469238 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to compute all the pairs separately and then collect the pairs you want.

```
def get_pairs(l, difference):
    pairs = []
    # first compute all pairs: n choose 2 which is O(n^2)
    for i in xrange(len(l)):
        for j in xrange(i+1, len(l)):
            pairs.append((l[i], l[j]))

    # collect pairs you want: O(n^2)
    res = []
    for pair in pairs:
        if abs(pair[0] - pair[1]) <= difference:
            res.append(pair)
    return res

>>> get_pairs([1,2,3,4,2], 0)
>>> [(2, 2)]
>>> get_pairs([1,2,3,4,2], 1)
>>> [(1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 4), (3, 2)]
```

If you want to remove duplicates from you result, you can convert the `res` list to a set before you return it with `set(res)`.

Comment: It returns 1 on input list = [3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1] and d = 0 but should 2 (1,1; 1,1), because set doesn't count (1, 1) pair 2 times

Comment: If you are counting (1,1) multiple times, then there are 6 (1,1) pairs. In terms of indices, they will be `(l[1], l[3]), (l[1], l[4]), (l[1], l[5]), (l[3], l[4]) ...`

Comment: not really, if I have a list = [1, 1, 1, 1] and d = 0 there will be 2 pairs because it's allowed to count every number in pair only once

Comment: I am consistent with Python's itertools. For example `[x for x in itertools.combinations([1, 1, 1, 1], 2)]` returns `[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]`. But, if you have a different rule to compute the pairs, please feel free to modify the code as per your requirements :)

Comment: @Steve Also, suppose you had a list `[1, 2, 3]` and `d = 1`, which pair would you return? `(1, 2)` or `(2, 3)`?

Comment: output should be 1 in this case and it doesn matter wich one to count